# my recycler view in a fragments adapter getitem count showing zero,and not showing values in layout.but i add data to model class from api

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, adapter

[homepage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C9RbK.png)This is my `fragment` class

```
public class Premiums extends Fragment {
private RecyclerView recyclerPremium;
private RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;
private List<FeaturedAddDetails> featuredAddDetailsList = new ArrayList<>();
private List<PremiumDetails> premiumDetailslist = new ArrayList<>();
private NewestAdapter newestAdapter;
private PremiumAdapter premiumAdapter;
private String jsonResponse;
private PremiumDetails premiumDetails;
private JSONObject jsonobject;

public Premiums() {
}



@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View mainView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.premium_fragment, container, false);
    recyclerPremium = (RecyclerView) mainView.findViewById(R.id.recycler_premium);
    premiumAdd();
    premiumAdapter = new PremiumAdapter(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), premiumDetailslist);
    recyclerPremium.setAdapter(premiumAdapter);
    return mainView;
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
    recyclerPremium.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
    recyclerPremium.setHasFixedSize(true);
}

private void premiumAdd() {
    PremiumRequestHandler premiumHandler = new PremiumRequestHandler("premiumADD");
    premiumHandler.executeAsStringRequest(new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            Log.e("response", response);

            JSONArray jsonarray = null;
            try {
                jsonarray = new JSONArray(response);

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++) {
                try {
                    jsonobject = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);
                    Log.e("id", String.valueOf(jsonobject.getInt("id")));
                    premiumDetails = new PremiumDetails(jsonobject.getInt("id"),
                            jsonobject.getInt("userid"),
                            jsonobject.getInt("mobile"),
                            jsonobject.getInt("cityid"),
                            jsonobject.getInt("price"),
                            jsonobject.getInt("comments"),
                            jsonobject.getInt("created"),
                            jsonobject.getInt("categoryid"),
                            jsonobject.getInt("MainCategoryID"),
                            jsonobject.getInt("views"),
                            jsonobject.getInt("ImageCount"),
                            jsonobject.getInt("storeid"),
                            jsonobject.getString("title"),
                            jsonobject.getString("default_photo"),
                            jsonobject.getString("CityName"),
                            jsonobject.getString("CategoryName"),
                            jsonobject.getString("currency"),
                            jsonobject.getString("description"));
                    premiumDetailslist.add(premiumDetails);
                    premiumAdapter.setPremiumDetails(premiumDetailslist);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }



        }
    }, new BaseRequest.ErrorResponseCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onError(Exception exception) {

        }
    });


}
```

This is my `adapter` class

```
    public class PremiumAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<PremiumAdapter.MyViewHolderPremium> {
private List<PremiumDetails> premiumDetailsList;
private ImageLoader imageLoader;
private Context context;

public PremiumAdapter(Context context, List<PremiumDetails> premiumDetailsList) {
    this.premiumDetailsList = premiumDetailsList;
    this.context = context;
    notifyDataSetChanged();

}
public void setPremiumDetails(List<PremiumDetails> premiumDetailsList) {
    this.premiumDetailsList = premiumDetailsList;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}


public class MyViewHolderPremium extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder  {
    private TextView txtTitle,txtDescription,txtCityName,txtPrice,txtCategory,txtHour,txtPhotoNo;
    private NetworkImageView imgPhoto;
    public MyViewHolderPremium(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        txtTitle = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_title_fad);
        txtDescription = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.description_fad);
        txtCityName = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.city_name_fad);
        txtPrice = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.price_fad);
        txtCategory = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.category_fad);
        txtHour = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.hours_fad);
        txtPhotoNo = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_photo_no_fad);
        imgPhoto=(NetworkImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.img_photo_lod_fad);
    }
}

@Override
public MyViewHolderPremium onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.featured_ad_adapter_layout,parent,false);
    final MyViewHolderPremium myViewHolderPremium = new MyViewHolderPremium(itemView);
    return myViewHolderPremium;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolderPremium holder, int position) {
    PremiumDetails premiumDetails = premiumDetailsList.get(position);
    holder.txtTitle.setText(premiumDetails.getTitle());
    holder.txtDescription.setText(premiumDetails.getDescription());
    holder.txtCityName.setText(premiumDetails.getCityName());
    holder.txtPrice.setText(Integer.toString(premiumDetails.getPrice()));
    holder.txtCategory.setText(premiumDetails.getCategoryName());
    holder.txtHour.setText(Integer.toString(premiumDetails.getCreated()));
    holder.txtPhotoNo.setText(Integer.toString(premiumDetails.getImageCount())+" photos " );
    try {
        imageLoader= VolleyHandler.getImageLoader();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    //imageLoader = CustomVolleyRequest.getInstance(context).getImageLoader();
    //imageLoader.get(featuredAddDetails.getDefault_photo(), ImageLoader.getImageListener(holder.imgPhoto, R.mipmap.ic_launcher, android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert));


    holder.imgPhoto.setImageUrl(premiumDetails.getDefault_photo(),imageLoader);
}
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    Log.e("size", String.valueOf(premiumDetailsList.size()));
    return premiumDetailsList.size();
}}
```

I am getting error on showing values but I got values from `json` and I can't add it to `adapter` and model class, plz help me I look stackoverflow whole day but I can't find my issue
my `getItemCount()` is showing as 0"

Comment: is **Log.e("id", String.valueOf(jsonobject.getInt("id")));** showing value?

Comment: @Rahul Sharma yes it is showing 9 times

Answer (score 0):

Try `notifyDataSetChanged()` after setting data in the Constructor of your Adapter

[EDIT] Whenever your data changes, you need to inform your Adapter about it also, then call `notifyDataSetChanged()` on it.

You are probably setting empty data into the Adapter, your List changes, but the Adapter does not know about it.

[Update]
In addition to your Adapter constructor, add a setData(List) to your adapter to change your dataset at runtime.

```
 public void setPremiumDetails(List<PremiumDetails> premiumDetailsList) {
    this.premiumDetailsList = premiumDetailsList;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

When your request in `premiumAdd()` returns, and you receive a new set of data, you call `setPremiumDetails` on your Adapter with the new data and the List will update.

Comment: how to do that setting data in constructor

Comment: you already are with `this.premiumDetailsList = premiumDetailsList;` just call `notifyDataSetChanged()` after that. If `getItemCount()` still returns 0 after that, then your List must be empty.

Comment: still returns zero

Comment: Implement a `setData(List<PremiumDetails>)` in your Adapter and pass the List of data when you get your response. Your Adapter doesn't know about the changes of the Data yet, `notifyDataSetChanged` only works with the Data set in the Adapter.

Comment: where should i implement setData,when i try implement setData it showing error in adapter

Comment: no it not working and not showing any error but the value is not on the recycler,log shows size as 0,but it is executing 9 time because it showing log size 0 ,9 times

Comment: it should not get called that often, are you updating the Adapter inside the for loop? Update your Adapter when your dataset is ready. If you followed my suggestions then your adapter should be perfectly fine. Can you update your Question with the changes you made so far?

Comment: Okay nice! Try moving the line `premiumAdapter.setPremiumDetails(premiumDetailslist);` outside of your for-loop in `premiumAdd()`, set a Breakpoint on it and make sure your List of `premiumDetailslist` is not empty when you put it in the Adapter.

Comment: 'premiumDetailslist' is empty

Comment: That's your bug then.

Comment: i try to add data manually its working but i cant add the json data to adapter

Comment: Have you checked your JSON parsing results? Are the single `PremiumDetails` objects correctly instantiated? Why aren't you passing the JSON to the `PremiumDetails`constructor to do the parsing there? It would definitely improve the readability and maintainability of your code. While you're at it, check out GSON for simple deserialisation of JSONs.

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the adapter and then you are calling  premiumAdd() method.First call that method and then set the adapter.

```
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View mainView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.premium_fragment, container, false);
    recyclerPremium = (RecyclerView) mainView.findViewById(R.id.recycler_premium);
    premiumAdd();
    premiumAdapter = new PremiumAdapter(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), premiumDetailslist);
    recyclerPremium.setAdapter(premiumAdapter);
    return mainView;
```

Comment: i tried this also but its also not working my adapter is calling already and it shows nine time log of getitemcount after that only response is logging

Comment: no error but the data is not showing on recyclerview

Comment: Try removing notifyDataSetChanged() and check what happenes

Comment: It logs E/size 0 for 6times,after that E/id: 14119686 for 9 times ,id changing 9 times

Answer (score 0):

your notifiy adapter on every single add

```
for (...){
   ....
    premiumDetailslist.add(premiumDetails);
    premiumAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();// called every time wrong
}
```

also provide what exact error log says

and move the notifyDataSetChanged() after the for not in  the loop

if no data is showing try recyclerview.invalidate , but i wont particularly do that way, would try debugging, log every step, inspect with method in the expected sequence isnt working

Comment: no error showing but no values are showing in recyclerview

Answer (score 0):

```
      @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View mainView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.premium_fragment, container, false);
            recyclerPremium = (RecyclerView) mainView.findViewById(R.id.recycler_premium);
            mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
            recyclerPremium.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
            recyclerPremium.setHasFixedSize(true);
            premiumAdd();
            premiumAdapter = new PremiumAdapter(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), premiumDetailslist);
            recyclerPremium.setAdapter(premiumAdapter);
            return mainView;
        }
```

and remove `premiumAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`

added adapter code:

```
public class RVAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RVAdapter.ViewHolder> {
ArrayList<Model> dataset;

public RVAdapter(ArrayList<Model> dataset) {
    this.dataset = dataset;
}

@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.rv_item,parent,false);
    return new ViewHolder(v);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Model model = dataset.get(position);
    holder.name.setText(model.name) ;
    holder.status.setText(model.status);
    if (model.status.equalsIgnoreCase("good"))
        holder.ivStatus.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_tick_48);
    else
        holder.ivStatus.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_delete_48);

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    Log.e("TAG","SIZE: "+dataset.size());
    return dataset.size();
}

public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    TextView name;
    TextView status;
    ImageView ivStatus;
    RelativeLayout parent;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        name = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.rv_item_name);
        status = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.rv_item_status);
        ivStatus = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.rv_item_iv);
        parent = (RelativeLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.rv_item_parent);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: not its not working still not showing data and now the log inside the getItem is not showing